# Find URLs in text and replace them with their domain name

Tags: python, regex, url

I am working on an NLP project and I want to replace all the URLs in a text with their domain name to simplify my corpora.

An example of this could be:

```
Input: Ask questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
Output: Ask questions here stackoverflow.com
```

At this moment I am finding the urls with the following RE:

```
urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', text)
```

And then I iterate over them to get the domain name:

```
doms = [re.findall(r'^(?:https?:)?(?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+)',url) for url in urls]
```

And then I simply replace each URL with its dom.

This is not an optimal approach and I am wondering if someone has a better solution for this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = 'Ask questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, new stuff here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/, Final ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565514/find-urls-in-text-and-replace-them-with-their-domain-name mail server here mail.inbox.com/whatever'
new_s = re.sub('https*://[\w\.]+\.com[\w/\-]+|https*://[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com/[\w/\-]+', lambda x:re.findall('(?<=\://)[\w\.]+\.com|[\w\.]+\.com', x.group())[0], s)
```

Output:

```
'Ask questions here stackoverflow.com, new stuff here stackoverflow.com, Final ask stackoverflow.com mail server here mail.inbox.com'
```

Comment: This fails when the url has parameters, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565514/

Comment: @m33n It should work now. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: I am afraid it does not: https://mail.inbox.com can make it fail because of that double point

Comment: @m33n What is your desired output from the string, if it includes the url that you just posted?

Comment: I the input is "https ://mail.inbox.com/whatever" I would like to get "mail.inbox.com" (i just added the whitespace to avoid the url formatting)

Comment: @m33n I made an additional change the handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You also might match a pattern `http\S+` that starts with http and then matches not a whitespace to match the url. The  parse the url and return the hostname part:

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse

subject = "Ask questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/"
print(re.sub("http\S+", lambda match: urlparse(match.group()).hostname, subject))
```

[Demo Python 3](http://rextester.com/JFN90913)

[Demo Python 2](http://rextester.com/YUJRG81284)

**Edit**: if the string can start with http or www you might use [`(?:http|www\.)\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/7RnJk1/1):

```
def checkLink(str):
    str = str.group(0)
    if not str.startswith('http'):
        str = '//' + str
    return urlparse(str).hostname
print(re.sub("(?:http|www\.)\S+", checkLink, subject))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/XQIZ35883)

Comment: The url could start with http or www